# How to skip bundle updates when doing migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

When I tried to create a new migration for db, the newest code forced me to do 'bundle install', but because of some network problem I cannot update the gems. Is there an option for migration I can skip updating bundles?

```
jimmy-mac:new_app jimmy$ rails g migration remove_title_from_offer

Could not find webrat-0.7.3 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

Comment: why you want avoid it because you need it when you start your application ?

Comment: @shingara: I just want to skip it temporarily because I cannot do migration if I don't update my bundles. But due to some network problem, the update always failed.

Comment: I found one solution. After I read http://gembundler.com/rationale.html, I noticed that webrat gem is in the group of 'test', so I run 'bundle install --without test', then the migration can continue!

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle exec rails g migration remove_title_from_offer
```

perhaps? Or you could just create a new migration by hand...

Comment: Thank you @stef, but this command cannot work either. I can create a migration by hand indeed, I just want to find a solution that can isolate rails from the bundler for the moment.